# Adaptive bitrate HLS not working with Google Cast SDK

Tags: http-live-streaming, chromecast

I am using the latest version of the Chrome Sender (v1 of the new public release) and I am running into issues getting HLS to work.

My m3u8 manifest is a "master" playlist that points to six other m3u8 playlists of various resolutions and bitrates in order to provide adaptive bitrate streaming as per the spec.

This playlist is well tested in works in my custom Roku app, my iOS app (with Apple TV as well), and even in the browser via Flash (JWPlayer Pro).  It also works directly in Safari on iOS. The only thing that is a little different about my playlists is that they contain query string parameters that enforce an expiration of the content but this is allowed in the HLS spec.  For example: `playlist.m3u8?expires=1391662909&signature=I3G8RKUkILOwxjZy8EyL5w%3D%3D%24q0WbXA2whSNFAj0Os3NIpfHkqMA%2BH2iqMMjm0xH2CYKNe3jh1jgl%2FUdS39ve%0AFnL%2F`

Here is the code in my Chrome Sender where I am setting the playlist URL:

```
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo('http://master_playlist_url.m3u8');
mediaInfo.contentType = 'application/x-mpegURL';

var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
request.autoplay = true;
request.currentTime = 0;

session.loadMedia(request, onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'), onMediaError);
```

The media does not load and `onMediaError` is invoked with an error object containing the following:

```
code: "session_error"
description: "LOAD_FAILED"
details: null
```

I've also tried setting `streamType` to `chrome.cast.media.StreamType.BUFFERED`, `chrome.cast.media.StreamType.LIVE`, and `chrome.cast.media.StreamType.OTHER` each with the same result.  I have also tried setting `duration` with no luck. I tried removing `autoplay` and `currentTime` on LoadRequest but no luck either.

My receiver is a basic Custom Receiver as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cast</title>
  <script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id='media' width="100%" height="auto" />
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
      window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(window.mediaElement);
      window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
      window.castReceiverManager.start();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the updated docs HLS is now supported but I can't seem to get it to work: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

I should also mention this code works fine when using a progressive MP4 and changing the content type to `video/mp4`.

UPDATE:
I decided to try removing the master playlist (adaptive bitrate streaming) from the mix and just go with a single m3u8 playlist that contains one quality of TS segments. It produced the same exact error. So at least we know the problem isn't related to adaptive bitrate streaming specifically but the entirety of HLS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive BitRate protocols need the [Media Player Library](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cast/docs/player). Take a look at either the [Cast Media Player Library Sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample) or the [Cast Custom Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver) samples.

Comment: Thanks Les, I didn't notice the part about adding the Media Player library to my receiver. I've done that and now I'm no longer getting an error but neither `onMediaDiscovered` nor `onMediaError` are invoked after calling `loadMedia` on the session. I have debugging enabled on the receiver.

Comment: Write a new Q, and post your log and your Receiver, be sure to obscure any PII.

Comment: I ended up using the example receiver in your link that displays all the debug info on screen and now onMediaError is getting called.  Here are the details: code: "session_error", description: "LOAD_FAILED". On the receiver debugging output it just shows me all the parameters I passed in on the MediaInfo object.  Is there any way to get more detail about what error is taking place?

Comment: I posted my previous comment at almost the same time you posted yours, I will post as a new question with more detail.  Thanks

Comment: I have posted as a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633991/error-loading-hls-playlist-in-cast-receiver)